# Getting "XQueryException", Unexpected token syntax error

Tags: java, exception, marklogic

I have created Xdbc database connection and run the sample program it was successful.
I have created class `markLogics.java` and imported the jar file `marklogic-xcc-4.0.1.jar`

**Code Snapshot:**

```java
package com.marklogic;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSource;
import com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSourceFactory;
import com.marklogic.xcc.Session;
import com.marklogic.xcc.Request;
import com.marklogic.xcc.ResultSequence;
import com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.RequestException;
import com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XccConfigException;**

class markLogics {
public static void main(String args[]) throws XccConfigException,
        RequestException {
    URI uri = null;
    try {
        uri = new URI("xcc://user:pwd@localhost:8008/Marklogics");
        // uri=new URI("");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String queryResult = "";
    ContentSource contentSource = ContentSourceFactory
            .newContentSource(uri);
    Session session = contentSource.newSession();
    String queryStr = "let $uri := xdmp:get-request-field(\"uri\")"
            + "return"
            + "if (empty($uri) or $uri eq\"\") then"
            + "("
            + " xdmp:set-response-content-type(\"\text/html\"),"
            + "<ul>"
            + "{for $i in collection()"
            + "let $doc := document-uri($i)    return"
            + "<li>"
            + "<a href="
            + "\"view.xqy?uri={xdmp:url-encode($doc)}\""
            + " >{$doc}</a></li>"
            + "}</ul>)"
            + "else (   xdmp:set-response-content-type(\"text/xml\"),   if (empty(doc($uri)))"
            + "then <error>No content" + "</error>    else doc($uri)  )";
    // String
    // queryStr="let $uri := xdmp:get-request-field(\"uri\")for $v in $doc//uri    $a in $doc//play";
    Request request = session.newAdhocQuery(queryStr);
    try {
        ResultSequence rs = session.submitRequest(request);
        System.out.println(rs.asString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    session.close();
}
```

}

While executing the code, I get that exception :

```
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_on line 1
expr:
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.ServerExceptionHandler.handleResponse(ServerExceptionHandler.java:31)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.EvalRequestController.serverDialog(EvalRequestController.java:68)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:72)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:280)
    at com.marklogic.markLogics.main(test.java:34)
```

***Understanding:***

According to my understanding in the query I have call use the `view.xqy` file that is throwing the exception.

Approach Follows:
I have tried the following approach to overcome this by archiving the the `view.xqy` and added into build path of the project, but it does not help me out.

Could you give me some guidance to overcome the hiccups?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I suspect that your problems have to do with Java string concatenation: for example, there is no whitespace between "return" and "if..." in `queryStr`. Each component of `queryStr` probably needs to begin or end with some whitespace.

But it may be better to take a step back and try a simpler approach, with native HTTP instead of Java. It looks to me like you are trying to build a web application, with an index page that renders a list of links. You will probably find that easier to do in pure HTTP.

So I would move your `queryStr` XQuery into an `index.xqy` file, and place that file in the `modules root` of an `HTTPServer`. Place `view.xqy` in the same location. Use an ordinary web browser to connect to `http://HOSTNAME:PORT/`, filling in the correct `HOSTNAME` and `PORT`.

Possibly you will need to integrate Java later on, but I think it will help your confidence if you get a simple HTTP application working first.

More reading:

- http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/2009-01-get-started-apps
- http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/2009-07-search-api-walkthrough
- http://developer.marklogic.com/code/bill

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the idea above that you are MUCH better off storing XQuery on the server and invoking it via `HTTP` or `XCC`.

The typical approach for `XQuery` generally and MarkLogic in particular is to store the code in the "root" area pointed to by an Application Server, then simply invoke the `XQuery`. Concatenating **ad-hoc** xquery as a string has a few problems:

It is hard to type - no syntax highlighting or other tooling

The `XQuery` must be re-parsed every time, rather than cached in an efficient form

You can't build a well-thought-out `XQuery` application that way. `XQuery` has modules for code organization, and you can search your XQuery separately for particular `XML` elements and attributes, as well as invoked functions if you separate your `XQuery` code and keep it on the server

`XQuery` is purely functional, so coding is naturally interactive and iterative, which is much easier in an interactive query buffer such as **cq or queryConsole**, which are packaged with MarkLogic.